# Is Roderick Kingsley supposed to be a dig at a Marvel Executive?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

I've been catching up with Superior Spider-Man, and can't help but wonder if [Roderick Kingsley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roderick_Kingsley), the original Hob-Goblin, is supposed to be an analogue for a real-life person within Marvel Entertainment?

His MO is to license out 'Characters' in order to generate revenue from royalty payments. If this isn't a deliberate reflection of what Marvel's strategy has been for the last decade or so, I don't know what is. It seems to be a very deliberate and not-so-subtle symmetry, but by making *a villain* the architect of this scheme, it seems to be criticizing the decision to do so.

I don't understand where the criticism stems from, or who the individual executive Kingsley is mimicking/denouncing (if it is *only one person*).

Anyone who is even vaguely aware of Marvel's history knows the decision to license its properties was the key to saving Marvel from bankruptcy, and ultimately created a proving ground for Marvel to create Marvel Studios, which is by far Marvel's strongest property (financially, at least). I don't understand how this could be considered *a bad thing*, particularly as an opinion expressed within Marvel's pages themselves: **and** in Spiderman, their flagship title no less!

- Avi Arad and Isaac Perlmutter were the ones who initiated the
  licencing decision, and are both largely revered as being the saviors
  of Marvel, so I don't see how they could be targets (although,
  narratively, their actions are closest to the MO of Kingsley)
- Joe Quesada, whilst much-maligned, has no control/say over licensing
  decisions, as the comics are a subsidiary and as such lower down the
  pecking order of the corporate structure, so he can't be it.
- Stan Lee, who conceived and ran with idea of licensing the characters
  out in the 70's (abortively, unless you count *The Incredible Hulk*)
  is the most revered man in the business, and considering his age and
  ailing health, I don't think a criticism of his business strategy
  would have cleared it though the bullpen at this point.

So who's left? There are obviously some strong parallels, but I can't connect the dots and figure out who **THE REAL HOBGOBLIN IS?**

Good luck, True Believers. I'm counting on you.

Comment: “His MO is to license out 'Characters' in order to generate revenue from royalty payments. If this isn't a deliberate reflection of what Marvel's strategy has been for the last decade or so, I don't know what is.” Well, like you say, for at least the last 7 years their strategy has been focused on Marvel Studios, where (if I understand correctly) they control the rights to their characters instead of licensing them out.

Comment: Marvel Studios is a (relatively) recent emergence, and the conditions of its fruition were predicated on the leverage built by building there characters through licensing to Fox (*X-Men*) and Sony (*Spiderman*). The very idea of licensed characters is widely attributed to Marvel, it's been (until recently) their bread and butter, and it saved their enterprise. I can't figure out what/whom this character is critical of.

Comment: Just because a decision is the correct one, doesn't mean it won't have its detractors. To keep it in the *Marvel* Universe, in the film version of *The Avengers* everyone seems to have a problem with Nick Fury's entirely correct and logical decision to make superweapons after Loki and Thor decide to flatten New Mexico. That might help you a little in figuring out who Kingsley is based on.

Comment: It doesn't...? I'm aware there will always be people complaining, but this is seemingly an attack on a real world analogue of Marvel *within the pages of Spiderman.* It isn't a plot point of a Movie, its a veiled criticism of what appears to be a real person...but whom?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: I was really just querying the “last decade” part. [Marvel Studios started working on *Iron Man* independently in November 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man_(2008_film)#Development#cite_ref-42), and [had the shared universe strategy in mind then too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Development), so strategy-wise, it’s not *that* recent. (*Iron Man* came out in 2008. That’s 6 years ago now.) If anything, I’d guess the Hobgoblin’s actions are a reference to “here’s what we used to do, didn’t it suck?”

Comment: "Last decade *or so*"... there's no need for nitpicking though. So you believe its an attack on their over all strategy,  not an individual.

Comment: My question is why are you so sure that Hobgoblin is a dig at anyone in Marvel?  Hobgoblin was revealed to be Robert Kingsley in 1983 which is over three decades ago.  I don't know much about Marvel's licensing history, but it's my understanding that most of it happened in the 90s not the early 80s when this character was created.

Comment: We're discussing the actions of a character in modern comics, not the conditions/intentions of his original release. Its a plot point, not a question about kingsleys original character.

Comment: @numaroth, it could be argued that their actual strategy is following hobgoblin, and not vise versa.  It might be ironic then, that in following the bad guy strategy they became great and became good guys.  I wonder if there are other such "do what was once considered the bad-guy approach, and it turns out that you become both great and good" - in entertainment.